# JSONcpp - trying to deserialize to variables

Tags: c++, json, deserialization, jsoncpp

How to deserialize `data` values?

```
{"data": 
    [{
        "Id": 3, 
        "Name" : "Wind", 
        "Type" : 2, 
        "Order" : 1, 
        "user" : "Mike"
    }], 
    "free" : 0, 
    "line" : 10, 
    "count" : 1
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class Class {
public: 
    virtual ~Class(void);
    virtual void Serialize(Json::Value& root); 
    virtual void Deserialize(Json::Value& root); 

    int Id;
    std::string free;
    std::string line;
    std::string count;
    std::vector<std::string> ID;

};

void Class::Serialize(Json::Value& root) {
    // ...
}

void Class::Deserialize(Json::Value& root) {

     free = root.get("top", 0).asInt();
     line = root.get("skip", 0).asInt();
     count = root.get("count", 0).asInt();

    Json::Value Data= root["data"];
    Id = Data.get("Id", 0).asInt();
}
```

I cannot deserialize the Data element `Id`, etc. The elements `free`, `line` and `count` can be extracted.

I have tried to create a second class to separate them, but that would not work either.

Comment: Why are you not able to deserialize it? This would be very interesting. And maybe if you can answer this question, you can ask us a question for your problem?

Comment: edit typo in that  int Ids       ids= Data.get("Id", 0).asInt();

Comment: those int defines are in the class sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON element `data` is an array. You missed the index of its element that you want to access.

At the moment, it has only one element so the index would be 0 i.e. `Data[0]`.

Example:

```
Id = Data[0].get("Id", 0).asInt();
         ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, tried the array index on somethings before and it did not work.